# How do I change the cardview position to the bottom of the tablayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I tried to create a cardview consisting of five items in a fragment. However, the cardview position is always at the top of the layout. I tried using margin and align, but it didn't work.
How do I change the position of the cardview?

Here is my card_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android.support.v7.cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="85dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/my_relative_layout"
>


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#E3F0F5"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:elevation="14dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/iv_image"
            android:src="@drawable/avatar1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#95989A"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_text"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_image"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#95989A"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_blah"
            android:text="Another RV Fragment"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_text"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_image"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_image"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my activity_pendaftar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.martin.app.donorkuyadmin.PendaftarActivity"
android:background="@drawable/background4">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_pendaftar">
    </include>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill">
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Please add the main layout xml file.

Comment: @vikashkumarpandey Okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give an `id` to your `AppBarLayout` (say, *id=action_bar*) and then simply add `layout_below="@id/action_bar"` to your `ViewPager`:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_below="@id/action_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Coordinator layout instead of Relative layout and set layout_behavior property into view pager to appbar_scrolling_view_behavior.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_pendaftar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your `include` statement outside the `appbarlayout` and align it to parent's bottom like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.martin.app.donorkuyadmin.PendaftarActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background4">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill">
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <include
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_pendaftar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </include>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It did not work. It just changes the position of my toolbar, not the cardview :D